# How do i give a value to TextBox when i click on him vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have text box create like that:

```
Dim Result1 As New TextBox
Result1.ID = "BOX_Result" & a & "_" & i
```

I want when i click on that textbox to write "OK" and when i double click in cell to put NOT/OK

Comment: Look up javascript and its flavors

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with events:

```
Private Sub Result1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Result1.Text = "OK"
End Sub

Private Sub Result1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Result1.Text = "NOT/OK"
End Sub
```

Just add event handlers with above solution:

```
Dim Result1 As New TextBox
Result1.ID = "BOX_Result" & a & "_" & i
AddHandler Result1.Click, AddressOf Me.Result1_Click
AddHandler Result1.DoubleClick, AddressOf Me.Result1_DoubleClick
```

Other solution:

```
Dim Result1 As New TextBox
Result1.ID = "BOX_Result" & a & "_" & i
Result1.Click += Function(sender, e) 
Result1.Text = "OK"
End Function
Result1.DoubleClick += Function(sender, e) 
Result1.Text = "NOT/OK"
End Function
```

Comment: Doesn't work Result1.Click += Function(sender, e) , when i put Result1. doesn't have click

Comment: if it works you will also need to remove those handlers when you close your app

Comment: And i have error when i write Private sub Result1_Click because Result1_Click is not declarare, is dynamic created

Comment: i removed handles on the end of events.

Comment: AddHandler Result1.Click, AddressOf Me.Result1_Click, error on Click